# Home wifi to phone 1 mile away

Tags: wireless-networking, router

What do I need to get my home WiFi to reach my phone at work a 1/4 mile away. Any help? I have looked all over for an answe but can not find one.

Answer (score 9):

There's these pesky things called "Physics" and "Legal regulation of power and frequency bands"

The amount of power needed to transmit follows something called the [inverse square law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_propagation) - transmission power doubles with distance. You could, in theory, use highly directional antennae on either end (which are more efficient since you arn't blasting signal everywhere), or increase your transmission power on both ends. Of course, you'd need more power for the latter, and the former only goes so far. And at some point, increasing power means you're causing fried birds to fall out of the sky....

And we haven't even started on line of sight affecting signal quality and strength, and how wifi can be attenuated by walls. For that matter, I've picked up nearby access points whose signal strength varies with weather.

In short, its just not possible without specialised equipment designed to do this - you might be able to do this with ham radio, or even some sneaky stuff with unlienced radio, but without breaking a lot of laws, or doing heavy mods at both ends of your setup.

Comment: The upside of fried birds falling out of the sky is that you don't have to worry about what to eat for dinner!

Answer (score 3):

you would need a directional antenna at each site, this is assuming you could achieve LOS (line of site).

There are various sites that can give you an idea of what hardware you will need and how much you need to boost the signal.

You could try searching for "long range wifi directional antenna"

Example [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/39902-43-long-range-miles-directional-wifi-signal-boosting).

Comment: Ok, so what do I use for the cell phone end?

Comment: You would need a long range directional antenna **on both ends**. Please read the entire thread that cobalt74 linked to. It's correct.

Comment: Maybe elaborate on what problem your trying to solve.

Comment: If you're only trying to go 1/4 mile and have a near line-of-site, you may be okay with just a directional antenna on the base end.

Comment: Most phones do have horrible wireless range though. Small antennas, inside a case.